# Visual Studio 2017 and GIT with external project

Tags: git, project, solution

I'm trying to use GIT with Visual Studio.
The situation is this:

- \Base\Routines\Routines.csproj
- \Base\Service\Service.sln
- \Base\Service\MyApp\MyApp.csproj

The service solution includes the Routines project. As you can see the Routines project is in an external folder from Service solutions.
I want to create my GIT repository in Service folder and not in Base folder. VS tells me projects external will be not included.

What is the best practice? I must make a copy of my routines project into my service folder or there is another way?

Comment: Use a git submodule or publish a nuget package that you will include in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `gitsubmodule`. So, your solution will be in git repository, and `Routines` project will have its own git repository. And then, you could include your `Routines` project repository as submodule for `Service` repository.
Check [this link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule), for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all projects within same base folder e.g: basefolder/project1, basefolder/project2 and then when creating git repo you can give path to basefolder. This way all folders/files within basefolder will be included/tracked. Tested this on vs 2022 community version.